# VSE: How to add border to strip

Tags: video-sequence-editor, masking

I am trying to do a composition of two videos, one being full-screen while the second one appears as a small window in one corner, as in the following example: [image: Example of current composition]

Ideally, I would like to round the corners of the video at the corner and add some border to it:

[image: Picture-in-picture with rounded corners and border]

I couldn't find information about how to achieve this result. I tryied to create a mask by
VFX->Masking but I only managed to create a rounded rectangle by combining rectangles and circles, but this solution makes it hard to adjust the settings.

If rounding corners has no simple solution, it would fi fine just to add a border to the video.

[image: Picture in picture with border only]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might try something involving blurring a mask and then doing a greater than comparison on it.

Comment: You could mix the 2 videos in the Compositor with a mask as factor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### version Compositor

TheLabCat's comment in images :) just ... I don't think VSE can handle this blur task, so ... version in compositor.

[image]
[image]
Originally I used Math node > Less than 0.5, but edge was jagged (without antialiasing) so I used ColorRamp node instead.

### version Sequencer

For VSE you would have to use Mask (in a current version there is not an one click solution like in other apps, but on other hand with this system you have open a gate to endless and much more complex and animated masks.

It will be hard to create round corner in native blender's Mask system with rounded corners (seen under Paint Editor).
Would be probably more easier to create a "mask" object in 3Dviewport (or use bw image imported as a strip).

**Here is example with mask from Scene ...**
You already have one scene with VSE setup. Create another Scene in the same file and in 3Dviewport set Camera to Orthographic, Add a Plane at location you want to see *Small Screen* through Camera, add Solidify+Bevel modifiers, set white material and black world ...

[image]
Left camera is the mask for *SmallScreen*, right camera with Plane is duplicated + one more Solidify modifier. It will works like a stroke  thickness for Colour strip :)

So you should see something like this ...

[image]

In your VSE scene add two *Scene* strips (containing your masks) and under properties choose corresponding *Camera* object. Strips can be placed whenever you want (or hide them). We need them just for strip modifiers.

For *Small Scree*n add *Mask* Modifier > *Strip* and choose *Scene* strip with mask done at the first camera. For a stroke add *Color* strip and ad *Mask* modifier > *Strip* > *Scene* with camera two ...

[image]
[image]

File contains both version ...
[image]

To be more flexible you can create a rounded mask for entire screen, and under VSE apply mask to "small" screen at size of full screen, group strips and transform (scale, translate) whole group (image with stroke).